# Displaying other peoples facebook timelines on my site

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've got a website I'm doing around a bunch of athletes.

All of these athletes have a Facebook account.

The client wants to show each of these athletes Facebook timelines on their individual profile pages using only their Facebook profile handle that they will provide.

I'm very unfamiliar with the Facebook API but am 99% sure this isn't possible as each of the athletes would have to go to the Facebook developers portal and set up an app right?

Is there any way to achieve this at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nop, you're wrong. Your athletes don't have to setup an app. But, on the other hand, you or the developer responsible for that project, must setup an app at the Facebook developers website.

I'm not going to explain all the process, since the Facebook docs are quite easy to understand.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/

After you setup your facebook app and integrate it with your website, it's time to start asking the athletes authorization you have plenty of ways to do that, you can either use [Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/), [Dialogs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/) or even[Manually Build a Login Flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/).

Keep in mind that you have different permissions, here's a [full list of the permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions) and a small description explaining what's their purpose.

Each athlete would have to grant permissions to your app, then after they do that, you will get an **Access Token** and the **Facebook User ID**, usually the **Access Token** has a short period of life (aprox. 2 hours), but you can trade this **Access Token** for a long one with a life time of aprox. 60 days. You can read more about **Access Tokens** [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/)

After your athletes grant permissions to your app, you can access to their timelines. Keep in mind that it won't be exactly as their timeline on Facebook. To grab user info you can either use [Graph API nodes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api), or if need a more complex and detailed info you can query it using [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)

Comment: Thanks very much for your clear explanation... further research led me to the same solution so nice to have it confirmed.